# How to sell items marked as sellable?

Tags: rage

In Rage by Bethesda, there are several items marked "sellable" that have no use other than sale.

How do I sell them? All that appears when I go to a merchant and try to sell stuff is the supplies. I'm certain I have these items, as they are in my inventory, but they are not shown when I try to sell them to a merchant.

I was successful in doing so very early in the game, but not anymore. Pressing R1 takes me straight to ammo to sell.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody asked the same question [here](https://www.supercheats.com/playstation3/questions/rage/237747/how-do-i-sell-items-in-my-inve.htm).

When interacting with a vendor press the on-screen prompt to switch from purchasing items to selling your gear (Default Square PS3/X X360) and then use the bumpers on your controller to switch categories of gear you can sell (Default LB/RB). This allows you to sell supplies, gear, or ammunition.

Refer to Rage's wikia page on [vendors](https://rage.fandom.com/wiki/Vendors) for a list of people you can sell gear to and what gear is safe to sell.